# Update database field in which Json_Object into Json_Array in mysql8

Tags: arrays, json, mysql-8.0

I want to Update this JSON Array w.r.t toUserId and deliveryStatus from the below table. I give `toUserId` and `deliveryStatus` = 0 and JSON object update .How can I achieve this in mysql8?

```
[{"seen": 0, "seenDate": 0, "toUserId": 148, "deliveryDate": 1634730012891, "deliveryStatus": 0}, {"seen": 0, "seenDate": 0, "toUserId": 270, "deliveryDate": 1634730013049, "deliveryStatus": 0}, {"seen": 0, "seenDate": 0, "toUserId": 160, "deliveryDate": 1634730013200, "deliveryStatus": 0}, {"seen": 0, "seenDate": 0, "toUserId": 262, "deliveryDate": 1634730013320, "deliveryStatus": 0}, {"seen": 0, "seenDate": 0, "toUserId": 263, "deliveryDate": 1634730013453, "deliveryStatus": 0}, {"seen": 0, "seenDate": 0, "toUserId": 264, "deliveryDate": 1634730013602, "deliveryStatus": 0}, {"seen": 0, "seenDate": 0, "toUserId": 265, "deliveryDate": 1634730013728, "deliveryStatus": 0}]
```

****expected** result** when i give toUserid 160 and also given deliveryStatus= 0

{"seen": 0, "seenDate": 0, "toUserId": 160, "deliveryDate": 1634730012891, "deliveryStatus": 0}

[image]

**Scenario:**
Its a group chat I update `toUserId` and mark `deliveryStatus` = 1 if user is online in specific jsonObject related `toUser`